# Statistics for java HashMap

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

During the lifecycle of a Java HashMap is there a way to determine how many collisions/chaining occured. How many times the HashMap was resized and how long each resize event took?

I checked source code for HashMap(1.6), and it looks like it can be extended to add the above functionality to it.

A little background, i have inherited some legacy application and since we are using CMS-GC, which happens to be non-compacting. These hashtables can have more than a million entries. We are facing some performance issues in production that occur only during activity spikes. And we have been unable to reproduce them in our production replica.

In my previous project we do print the our cache usage statistics periodically to determine their effectiveness.

Also would appreciate your opinion/criticism as to if this a right line of thinking?

Comment: `I checked source code for HashMap(1.6), and it looks like it can be extended to add the above functionality to it.`  What did you see that made you think this, and what approach did you have in mind?  Also - why do you now suspect this approach *doesn't* work, such that you're asking here?

Comment: I was looking for either criticism (bad idea) or opinion (please see this open source library). Google search did not yield any results so i was surprised. Usually most questions are answered by google results. Here is an interesting [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_codes_advanced_statistics.shtml) i found, not sure about the math behind it. I will post a followup of this exercise.

Comment: Java 8 has some useful updates to HashMap for performance. If you're lucky enough to be able to use Java 8 you should try it

Answer (score 1):

You are going on right track. You can extend Hashmap and override the methods by using counts. Based upon conditions you can increase the counts.

Update:
You can try to using Java's ManagementFactory API's that will give you more insights into  hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use a profiling tool such as [Dynatrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/index.html) to understand at runtime directly on your production environment what's going on. That's what we are using at my company.

As an alternative, if you don't have a Dynatrace license (nor want to do a POC to try it) I would try to use [Java Instrumentation API](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html) or aspects (with [aspectj](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/)) to do some profiling. That's a better solution than extending `HashMap` as you keep using the real classes your current application is using and thus don't have any side effects.

Another OTS option is to use a tool such as [Collection Spy](http://www.collectionspy.com/Page-Features-EN.htm) (but to be honest, I never used it).

I also found this interesting article about [profiling java applications with opensource tools](http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source/).

Comment: Java Instrumentation API looks interesting, we will certainly try that in the next version. Will also give Collection Spy a spin in non-prod environment - it has a two week trial period.